# get the data after in editable Table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app, frontend using HTML5, backend using Django.

There's a editable table in my frontend page.
I want to select the data using  jquery, but name and id selector all could not work for me.

```
               <table contenteditable='true' class="table table-bordered table-sm" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 1.0rem;"
                   id="bk-table"
                   data-toggle="table"
                   data-toolbar="#toolbar"
                   data-cookie="true"
                   data-cookie-id-table="materialId"
                   data-show-columns="true"
                   data-show-refresh="true"
                   data-show-fullscreen="true"
                   data-show-export="true"
                   data-height="650"
                    data-click-to-select="true"
                   data-id-field="id"
                   data-show-footer="true"
                   data-url="/api/materials/"
                   data-query-params="queryParams"
                   data-remember-order="true"
                   data-pagination="true"
                   data-side-pagination="server"
                   data-total-field="count"
                   data-data-field="results">
                <thead class="thead-dark" >
                <tr>
                      <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                    <th data-field="courseCode"  data-formatter="renderCourse">Course Code</th>
                    <th data-field="type">Course Type</th>
                    <th data-field="book.title">Course Material Title</th>
                    <th name="Author" data-field="book.author">Author/Editor</th>
                    <th  name="pub_date"  data-field="book.pub_date">Publication Year</th>                   

                </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

<script>
        $('#bk-table').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
            alert($('td[name="pub_date"]').val());   
});</script>
```

After editing the table, I have tried alert($('td[name="pub_date"]').val()),  alert($("[name='pub_date']").val()), none of the above could show the data in table, they all show "undefined" .

Comment: There is no TD in your table, can you post full table?

Comment: this is already the full table， no td in my table， the data cell r rendered using data-field

Comment: how can that be full table? you have no td in there. Anyway if thats your full table how you want to select any data if you are using the `td` selector in a `th`. At least make it `$('#bk-table').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
            alert($('th[name="pub_date"]').val());`

Comment: That's indeed my full table. If using th data-field=... to render the table, no td is needed. This is another method for displaying a table. I have tried alert($('th[name="pub_date"]').val());, but still "undefined" shows

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be the answer.
Otherwise post the full body of your table. 
You only post the header line of your Table.

```js
$('#bk-table').click(function() {
   if ($(this).attr("contentEditable") == "true") {
      console.log($('th[name="pub_date"]').text());   
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table contenteditable='true' class="table table-bordered table-sm" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 1.0rem;" id="bk-table" data-toggle="table" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-cookie="true" data-cookie-id-table="materialId" data-show-columns="true"
  data-show-refresh="true" data-show-fullscreen="true" data-show-export="true" data-height="650" data-click-to-select="true" data-id-field="id" data-show-footer="true" data-url="/api/materials/" data-query-params="queryParams" data-remember-order="true"
  data-pagination="true" data-side-pagination="server" data-total-field="count" data-data-field="results">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
      <th data-field="courseCode" data-formatter="renderCourse">Course Code</th>
      <th data-field="type">Course Type</th>
      <th data-field="book.title">Course Material Title</th>
      <th name="Author" data-field="book.author">Author/Editor</th>
      <th name="pub_date" data-field="book.pub_date">Publication Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: That's indeed my full table. If using th data-field=... to render the table, no td is needed. This is another method for displaying a table. I have tried your method, but only blank shows

Comment: Yes it's blank because you don' have a tbody in code. You posted just a thead with th. Just post your tbody and I will help you.

Comment: I render the data using data-field, no tbody needed using this method.

Comment: But there is no loop in your posted code. So you will get only one line or? Th is for your table head,

Comment: I have multiple lines, this is another method to show table, no need loop